# is_in_stock filter not working

Tags: magento-1.7, stock, collection-filtering, stock-status, out-of-stock

I am making a `Mage::getModel` call to try and get all products in a certain category that is in stock.

```
$stockIds = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addQtyFilter('<=',1)
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_in_stock', 1)
    ->getAllIds();

$_productCollection=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->load(51)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addIdFilter($stockIds)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setPageSize(10)->setCurPage(1);
```

Everything works apart from the `->addFieldToFilter('is_in_stock', 1)` line. Without it all products in the category show up. With it, it's filtering some (apparently random) products out, but not based on whether it is 'In stock'. Some out-of-stock items still appears, and some in-stock items do not appear.

I have checked that all the products are enabled and all quantities are at least 10.

### **How do I get all products in a certain category that is in stock?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first,`$stockIds` don't return the `product ids` ,it give the stock id,basically stock table primary key.
If you want to `filter product collection by  saleable` then you need use below code:

```
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($_productCollection)
```